# Error compiling react-native geocoder for android

Tags: android, react-native

Just wanted to try out the [RN GeoCoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder) for Android.

But I get the following errors during my build:

```
/GeoCoderTest/android/app/src/main/java/com/geocodertest/MainActivity.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
              ^
  symbol:   class List
  location: class MainActivity
GeoCoderTest/android/app/src/main/java/com/geocodertest/MainActivity.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
                   ^
  symbol:   class ReactPackage
  location: class MainActivity
/GeoCoderTest/android/app/src/main/java/com/geocodertest/MainActivity.java:15: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
GeoCoderTest/android/app/src/main/java/com/geocodertest/MainActivity.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
          new MainReactPackage(),
              ^
  symbol:   class MainReactPackage
  location: class MainActivity
/GeoCoderTest/android/app/src/main/java/com/geocodertest/MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                       ^
  symbol:   class ReactPackage
  location: class MainActivity
/GeoCoderTest/android/app/src/main/java/com/geocodertest/MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
               ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class MainActivity
6 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

I tried importing `java.util.Arrays` & `java.util.List`, however I was not sure of the ReactPackage and MainReactPackage classes and also the `@Override` annotation.

Looking forward for a feasible fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating MainApplication.java instead of MainActivity.java